# Delete Django Migrations

Tags: django, postgresql

I changed databases from mysql to postgre. Since there was no data in teh db yet, I just deleted the migrations folders for each of the apps. When I ran makemigrations afterwards though, I got this error:

```
/theme/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
from models import theme, theme_file
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

Everything worked fine before, nothing changed in the code other than the migrations folders being cleaned.

Any ideas?

```
   /Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/bin/python /Users/jl/Desktop/Bolts/manage.py runserver 8000
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x108e15ae8>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
        app_config.ready()
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
        self.module.autodiscover()
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
        autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
        import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
      File "/Users/jl/.virtualenvs/bolts3/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Users/jl/Desktop/Bolts/theme/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
        from models import theme, theme_file
    ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why the error would occur without any code being  changed.  But still, please try changing 'from models import' to 'from .models import' in line 2 of your /theme/admin.py file.

Comment: That was what I tried first.  Same result.

Comment: can you show us your project directory tree?

Comment: For the record, Django's ORM is largely backend-agnostic. You shouldn't need to touch your migrations when you change to a different backend.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleting the migrations will not fix the issue when you change database types. In your settings.py file, you must change the default database settings to point to your new PostgreSQL database, and also specify the schema, db user and password etc. Perhaps you haven't done this?

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm it would seem like you deleted a `__init__.py` file by accident?

Remember that a folder must have such file to be a python module, and when a folder it's a python module you can import from it.